# Gmail don't talk(send mail to me) with my SMTP server. Yahoo and Aol is ok

Tags: .net, vb.net, smtp, gmail

I have build a very very simple SMTP server in VB.NET, to only receive mails... i'm need that for a support ticket system.

I have tested my server, sending emails from Yahoo, Aol, and a Brazilian providor called BOL (www.bol.com.br), and it's working...

Sample of AOL incoming message on my server:

```
Starting listening on port 25


Client connected: 64.12.143.76:44965
>>> 220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready


<<< EHLO omr-m02.mx.aol.com
>>> 502 Command not implemented

<<< HELO omr-m02.mx.aol.com
>>> 250 raptor.agoge.com.br

<<< MAIL FROM:<fernando.nandissimo@aim.com>
>>> 250 OK

<<< RCPT TO:<f@frg.io>
>>> 250 OK

<<< DATA
>>> 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>

<<< Received: from mtaomg-mbd02.mx.aol.com (mtaomg-mbd02.mx.aol.com [172.26.252.16])
    by omr-m02.mx.aol.com (Outbound Mail Relay) with ESMTP id 1ED7C700000AB
    for <f@frg.io>; Tue, 22 Jul 2014 22:19:39 -0400 (EDT)
Received: from core-mpa004a.r1000.mail.aol.com (core-mpa004.r1000.mail.aol.com [172.29.184.13])
    by mtaomg-mbd02.mx.aol.com (OMAG/Core Interface) with ESMTP id E3BD638000082
    for <f@frg.io>; Tue, 22 Jul 2014 22:19:38 -0400 (EDT)
To: f@frg.io
Subject: hello, how are you
X-MB-Message-Source: WebUI
X-MB-Message-Type: User
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: Fernando Guimaraes <fernando.nandissimo@aim.com>
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
 boundary="--------MB_8D17433B04EB4D2_2B44_5B1EE_webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com"
X-Mailer: AOL Webmail STANDARD
Received: from 177.205.201.180 by webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com (205.188.93.240) with HTTP (WebMailUI); Tue, 22 Jul 2014 22:19:38 -0400
Message-Id: <8D17433B04C5371-2B44-1B49B@webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com>
X-Originating-IP: [177.205.201.180]
Date: Tue, 22 Jul 2014 22:19:38 -0400 (EDT)
x-aol-global-disposition: G
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mx.aim.com;
    s=20140625; t=1406081979;
    bh=N2MgG06dHoS+gfxHvx3fcZZfnE5ajRhrD7hZ6uGTXOo=;
    h=From:To:Subject:Message-Id:Date:MIME-Version:Content-Type;
    b=AjcPEJldvpndBhlEONuynHpGLH75o7YFoVVf1yJ4VH7t3XZuuLCoTQHHvsxP99i2M
     TOWiUfRLUqUBAwniVQnm3ccymbW56LlABsjMCfPXZdu0jEOnAvSzYcZDWXL7Pekfhf
     GBM0ZMWkM62zFcWPwATnoWT24dyrclQ1F1R7i19Y=
x-aol-sid: 3039ac1afc1053cf1bba3fb7

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
----------MB_8D17433B04EB4D2_2B44_5B1EE_webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"

hey!


i'm poking you... :)

----------MB_8D17433B04EB4D2_2B44_5B1EE_webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"

<font color=3D'black' size=3D'2' face=3D'arial'>hey!
<div><br>
</div>

<div>i'm poking you... :)</div>
</font>
----------MB_8D17433B04EB4D2_2B44_5B1EE_webmail-d298.sysops.aol.com--
.
>>> 250 OK

<<< QUIT
>>> 221 raptor.agoge.com.br closing transmission channel
```

Another sample of Yahoo mail:

```
Starting listening on port 25


Client connected: 98.136.216.146:33362
>>> 220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready


<<< EHLO nm27-vm3.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
>>> 502 Command not implemented

String unknow command: |EHLO nm27-vm3.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
|Binary unknow command: |45-48-4C-4F-20-6E-6D-32-37-2D-76-6D-33-2E-62-75-6C-6C-65-74-2E-6D-61-69-6C-2E-67-71-31-2E-79-61-68-6F-6F-2E-63-6F-6D-0D-0A|
<<< HELO nm27-vm3.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
>>> 250 raptor.agoge.com.br

<<< MAIL FROM:<dexterbhz@yahoo.com.br>
>>> 250 OK

<<< RCPT TO:<test@frg.io>
>>> 250 OK

<<< DATA
>>> 354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>

<<< Received: from [216.39.60.182] by nm27.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 23 Jul 2014 02:26:07 -0000
Received: from [98.137.12.192] by tm18.bullet.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 23 Jul 2014 02:26:07 -0000
Received: from [127.0.0.1] by omp1000.mail.gq1.yahoo.com with NNFMP; 23 Jul 2014 02:26:07 -0000
X-Yahoo-Newman-Property: ymail-3
X-Yahoo-Newman-Id: 66768.46477.bm@omp1000.mail.gq1.yahoo.com
Received: (qmail 17157 invoked by uid 60001); 23 Jul 2014 02:26:06 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com.br; s=s1024; t=1406082366; bh=6Nqij6v2JUJTeT0/BhAdXEB0UBBXs1FyYLy0j8zf6s0=; h=Message-ID:Date:From:Reply-To:Subject:To:MIME-Version:Content-Type; b=ikMGg1zk9izkqR5igwOCPcO/QSg6XVJhgIbq5CMiKGOmQp0XpSQXKRg87I3qBUCsx+d9U1bfMSGTdv9R/XrwFkAeNZd++ElFzsiCLhIvQe9QzQyRLpGc7E0/seMaeZYlMb16d2AE75zJWYnY1ziR/1LLXsBeDiO3aBgI5PlNnRA=
X-YMail-OSG: fg5x5oAVM1mGE8m_zI2LdNcCUFnHaR441eGqkmpjeD1r95V
 TiUs7_8L297g1K1P665uhi2_5kSfpsywr53tuodffiVbEVmAQdlYfnqgc0IY
 .s..ja4QTWjAv.QnKhFVgbRgsz8CaLLpw2kEoRAGnkkOW9MnP0aLg9bY1Ey.
 plPmoUJwnSoSUgx4pO2ZdCrdu0uvR7G6MCtzNcF6g2OBZmGQ6dtY_qqdUNcv
 9twltxpv6.iwQDBHwuheGxQRNdYNOP1WDwBqV9LrbFJ4sRAwIpDOt18wReUH
 gcdX5xhUb.VcqM273IRwYodK9JQumd_r3NGzIxlZ47KPzrLRbCHY9Fc2MrjS
 ujPF8pn5t814.gQvh2hVWnhXs0bAsSZFxH0UNGo3azIC8lukPcrVaFOn0o51
 sMrF9gR.KYJAScvycM2C6ShLgzvxylkFpVqBdYNVVYQmOjzt8fK78YiVGWeJ
 t0OEy0Rz21B74.hfydeYuExZKicFJlf1yjgS6tnv7o9DGLTuD2r5MAZ3YhLO
 vYK4F5PKOZLUM8q.YmZTrOg1kPi9kyEb.kQWl7I.MtkiWqjIuqlbEfA--
Received: from [177.205.201.180] by web164003.mail.gq1.yahoo.com via HTTP; Tue, 22 Jul 2014 19:26:06 PDT
X-Rocket-MIMEInfo: 002.001,SXQgd2lsbCB3b3JrPwEwAQEBAQ--
X-Mailer: YahooMailWebService/0.8.195.680
Message-ID: <1406082366.16792.YahooMailNeo@web164003.mail.gq1.yahoo.com>
Date: Tue, 22 Jul 2014 19:26:06 -0700
From: Fernando Guimaraes <dexterbhz@yahoo.com.br>
Reply-To: Fernando Guimaraes <dexterbhz@yahoo.com.br>
Subject: It will work?
To: "test@frg.io" <test@frg.io>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="133570123-1133622410-1406082366=:16792"

--133570123-1133622410-1406082366=:16792
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

It will work?
--133570123-1133622410-1406082366=:16792
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<html><body><div style=3D"color:#000; background-color:#fff; font-family:He=
lveticaNeue, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;fo=
nt-size:12pt"><div>It will work?</div></div></body></html>
--133570123-1133622410-1406082366=:16792--
>>> 250 OK

<<< .
>>> 250 OK

<<< QUIT
>>> 221 raptor.agoge.com.br closing transmission channel
```

But GMAIL don't talk with ME at all!!!

When GMAIL connects with me, they only sent that:

```
Starting listening on port 25


Client connected: 209.85.215.46:32845
>>> 220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready


<<< EHLO mail-la0-f46.google.com
QUIT
>>> 502 Command not implemented
```

And don't continue!?!... Why that? Should not GMAIL send HELO command after EHLO fails?

Here my VB.NET code to receive that mail:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1
    'Add a TEXTBOX1 to form
    'Add a TEXTBOX1 to form
    'Add a TEXTBOX1 to form
    'Add a TEXTBOX1 to form

    Private Server As Sockets.TcpListener
    Private Port As Integer = 25
    Private Thread As Thread

    Delegate Sub LogCallback(S As String)

    Sub Log(S As String)

        If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim d As LogCallback = AddressOf Log
            Me.Invoke(d, S)
        Else
            Me.TextBox1.AppendText(S.Replace("\n", vbCrLf))
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        Me.Text = String.Format("Listening port {0} v{1}", Port, AppVersion)

        Thread = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Listening))
        Thread.Start()
    End Sub

    Async Function Listening() As Task
        Server = New Sockets.TcpListener(Net.IPAddress.Any, Port)
        Server.Start()

        Log("Starting listening on port 25\n\n")

        Do
            Dim HandleThread As New Thread(New ParameterizedThreadStart(AddressOf HandleConnection))
            HandleThread.Start(Await Server.AcceptTcpClientAsync)
        Loop

    End Function

    Async Function HandleConnection(TcpClient As TcpClient) As Task

        Dim Stream As NetworkStream = TcpClient.GetStream

        Log(String.Format("\nClient connected: {0}\n", TcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString))
        Await R(Stream, String.Concat("220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready", vbCrLf))

        While True

            Do
                Dim BuffSize As Integer = 4096
                Dim Buffer As Byte() = New Byte(BuffSize - 1) {}
                Dim BytesRead As Integer

                BytesRead = Await Stream.ReadAsync(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)

                If BytesRead = 0 Then Exit Function


                Dim Msg As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer.Take(BytesRead).ToArray)

                Log(String.Concat("<<< ", Msg))

                If Msg.StartsWith("HELO") Then
                    Await R(Stream, "250 raptor.agoge.com.br")
                ElseIf Msg.StartsWith("MAIL") Or Msg.StartsWith("RCPT") Or Msg.StartsWith("Date") Or Msg.StartsWith("From") Then
                    Await R(Stream, "250 OK")
                ElseIf Msg.StartsWith("DATA") Then
                    Await R(Stream, "354 Start mail input; end with <CRLF>.<CRLF>")
                ElseIf Msg.StartsWith("From") Or Msg.StartsWith("Received") Then
                    Await R(Stream, "250 OK")
                ElseIf Msg = String.Concat(".", vbCrLf) Then
                    Await R(Stream, "250 OK")
                ElseIf Msg.StartsWith("QUIT") Then
                    Await R(Stream, "221 raptor.agoge.com.br closing transmission channel")
                    Stream.Close()
                    TcpClient.Close()
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Await R(Stream, "502 Command not implemented")

                End If
            Loop While Stream.DataAvailable

        End While

    End Function

    Private AppVersion As Integer = 32

    Async Function R(Stream As NetworkStream, Message As String) As Task

        Dim ResponseBuffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(String.Concat(Message, vbCrLf))
        Await Stream.WriteAsync(ResponseBuffer, 0, ResponseBuffer.Length)

        Log(String.Concat(">>> ", Message, vbCrLf, vbCrLf))
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: What does `Msg` actually contain when you receive a Gmail message? Is it just `QUIT`?

Comment: The message from Gmais 'EHLO mail-la0-f46.google.com <CRLF>QUIT'

Comment: Gmail returned the mail to sender with message 'Illegal response from remote server (too short)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem...

A single extra CRLF on 220 response was the problem...

Wrong Code

```
Await R(Stream, String.Concat("220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready", vbCrLf))
```

Correct Code

```
Await R(Stream, "220 raptor.agoge.com.br Simple Mail Transfer Service Ready")
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! And thanks for posting your solution :)